# When use Login Activity Template AS provided，I build failed with error：resource style/CardView not found

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio show the error messages as follow:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

  > Android resource linking failed
  >   Output:  error: resource style/CardView (aka com.example.kerne.myapplication:style/CardView) not found.
  >   E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4280: error: style attribute 'attr/cardElevation (aka com.example.kerne.myapplication:attr/cardElevation)' not found.
  >   E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:4281: error: style attribute 'attr/cardBackgroundColor (aka com.example.kerne.myapplication:attr/cardBackgroundColor)' not found.
  >   error: failed linking references.

  Command: C:\Users\Kerne.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\516d0ba81fb194b738ad96d8201bfccf\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Kerne\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.kerne.myapplication\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  error: resource style/CardView (aka com.example.kerne.myapplication:style/CardView) not found.
  C:\Users\Kerne.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-28.0.0.aar\ab02d6ef8e59cb2bf2d52ed920bf2ff8\res\values\values.xml:1089:5-1091:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/cardElevation (aka com.example.kerne.myapplication:attr/cardElevation)' not found.

  C:\Users\Kerne.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\design-28.0.0.aar\ab02d6ef8e59cb2bf2d52ed920bf2ff8\res\values\values.xml:1089:5-1091:11: AAPT: error: style attribute 'attr/cardBackgroundColor (aka com.example.kerne.myapplication:attr/cardBackgroundColor)' not found.

  error: failed linking references.
  Command: C:\Users\Kerne.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\516d0ba81fb194b738ad96d8201bfccf\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Kerne\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\
        E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.kerne.myapplication\
        -0\
        apk\
        --output-text-symbols\
        E:\MyProjects\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\symbols\debug\R.txt\
        --no-version-vectors
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #0

Comment: Is your compileSdk set to 28?

Comment: It is very strange，today when i build a login template，it success. I dont know what happened，but still thank you very much.